# APScheduler not trigger?

Tags: python, apscheduler

Why the job not trigger?

I would like to trigger the job at 01:00:00 everyday.

if I set the trigger time at 10 AM and run the py script. it will work. but at 1 AM, not trigger.

call print_jobs(),

```
Jobstore default:

    grab_star_baidu_news (trigger: cron[hour='1', minute='0', second='0'], next run at: 2014-02-26 01:00:00)

    grab_star_baidu_news_title (trigger: cron[hour='1', minute='30', second='0'], next run at: 2014-02-26 01:30:00)

    film_info_2_db (trigger: cron[hour='3', minute='0', second='0'], next run at: 2014-02-26 03:00:00)
```

My script like this(run on windows server 2012):

```
 from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
 import apscheduler
 import sys

 sys.path.append("E:\data")
 sch = Scheduler(daemonic=False)

 @sch.cron_schedule(hour="1", minute="0", second="0")
 def grab_star_baidu_news():
     import BaiduNewsMx
     BaiduNewsMx.GrabMxBaiduNews()


 @sch.cron_schedule(hour="1", minute="30", second="0")
 def grab_star_baidu_news_title():
     import BaiduNewsTitleMx
     BaiduNewsTitleMx.GrabBaiduMxNewsTitle()

 @sch.cron_schedule(hour="3", minute="0", second="0")
 def film_info_2_db():
     import InfoToDb
     InfoToDb.InsertFilmInfo2Db()

 #Job listener for completed and miss.
 def job_listener(ev):
     if ev.exception:
         print(str(ev.exception))
     else:
         print(str(ev.job))


 def job_complete(ev):
     #print('%s completed!', str(ev.job))
     sch.print_jobs()


 sch.add_listener(job_complete, apscheduler.events.EVENT_JOB_EXECUTED)
 sch.start()
 print("Schedule started.")
 sch.print_jobs()
```

Comment: I set the func(film_info_2_db) to run at 9:53 a.m, it worked. and print_jobs() info like this:
    film_info_2_db (trigger: cron[hour='9', minute='53', second='0'], next run at: 2014-02-27 09:53:00)

Comment: What version of Python do you have? Python 3.x on Windows has a known bug regarding Event.wait() which causes it to never wake up.